# XML nodes getting deleted when converting nested hash to XML in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, hash

I use the following code to convert hashes into XML:

```
class Hash
    def to_xml
        map do |k,v|
            text = Hash === v ? v.to_xml : v
            "<%s>%s</%s>" % [k,text,k]
        end.join
    end

    def to_xml_with_namespace(ns)
        map do |k,v|
            text = Hash === v ? v.to_xml_with_namespace(ns) : v
            "<#{ns}:%s>%s</#{ns}:%s>" % [k,text,k]
        end.join
    end
end
```

Everything works fine until I have multiple nodes with the same values, example:

```
{:users => { 
    :name_age_node => {:name => "Bob", :age => 50},
    :name_age_node => {:name => "Tom", :age => 45},
    :name_age_node => {:name => "Jess", :age => 22}
}
```

What outputs is simply the last node only.. The other nodes get overwritten for some reason. All nodes where there are not duplicate nodes with the same name are fine, whether they are nested or not.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: You can't have a Hash with the same key having multiple values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dealing with hashes. A hash only supports a single occurrence of a particular key:

```
foo = {:users => { 
    :name_age_node => {:name => "Bob", :age => 50},
    :name_age_node => {:name => "Tom", :age => 45},
    :name_age_node => {:name => "Jess", :age => 22}
  }
}
foo
# => {:users=>{:name_age_node=>{:name=>"Jess", :age=>22}}}
```

With unique keys:

```
foo = {:users => { 
    :name_age_node1 => {:name => "Bob", :age => 50},
    :name_age_node2 => {:name => "Tom", :age => 45},
    :name_age_node3 => {:name => "Jess", :age => 22}
  }
}
foo
# => {:users=>
#      {:name_age_node1=>{:name=>"Bob", :age=>50},
#       :name_age_node2=>{:name=>"Tom", :age=>45},
#       :name_age_node3=>{:name=>"Jess", :age=>22}}}
```

Or you could use an array of hashes to contain the inner data:

```
foo = {:users => [
    {:name => "Bob", :age => 50},
    {:name => "Tom", :age => 45},
    {:name => "Jess", :age => 22}
  ]
}
foo
# => {:users=>
#      [{:name=>"Bob", :age=>50},
#       {:name=>"Tom", :age=>45},
#       {:name=>"Jess", :age=>22}]}
#       :name_age_node3=>{:name=>"Jess", :age=>22}}}
```